# How make Menu top and fixed for SB Admin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, fixed

I would like to make menu top and fixed for SB Admin,

The template here. http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html

I tried with following navbar,

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

When am using this, there one scroll bar adding in the bottom of page.

I am a developer but not designer and is there any best method for that?

Comment: You can accept any answer if it helped you !

Answer (score 2):

Take out the inline `navbar-fixed-top`. Reference `.navbar` in your custom style sheet and give it the position of fixed.

```
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **`position`** property of HTML.

**`<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="position:fixed">`**

Answer (score 0):

in SB Admin you have `navbar-static-top` class, change to `navbar-fixed-top` and resolve your issue! but than you have to add `padding-top` to `<body>`, because `<navbar>` has it's own height:

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 ...
</nav>
```

CSS

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px; // height of navbar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class navbar-fixed-top will work only if you have included required bootstrap css for this. Better use CDN from official bootstrap site. Please ensure this first.

In case you are not using bootstrap you can simply set these rules.

```
 .navbar{
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
 .navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
 }
 body {
   padding-top: 70px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-default{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 405px 0;
}

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    #page-wrapper {
      position: inherit;
      margin: 0 0 0 250px;
      padding: 70px 30px 30px 30px;
      border-left: 1px solid darken(@gray-lightest, 6.5%);
    }
    .ocular-en-ipad-o-superior {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

and one more html

```
<metis-menu></metis-menu>
<div class="container-fluid" id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="ocular-en-ipad-o-superior" style="margin-bottom: 115px;"></div>
    <div ui-view=""></div>
</div>
```